# Laravel validation and updating a record

Tags: mysql, laravel, unique-constraint

In my user table in my database I have a unique key constraint set on `email` and `telephone` column to prevent duplicates.

My question is:

What happens when a user wants to update their records? When they submit the same email does it throw an error. When they try to use someone else's email what happens?

The reason for asking this is that I am using a request on my form to check user input against existing records in the database.

I'm using laravel's `unique:table_name` validator. I want to know if this throws an error if user wants to update their records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update, you need to add the `id` of that record to force the validator to ignore that given `id` for uniqueness, for example:

```
"unique:table_name,field_name,1" // Here 1 is the id to update that record
```

In this case, for example, if you have something like this:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,10'
```

Then `Laravel` will not check for uniqueness for record with id `10` and you need to set this rule when updating the record with id of `10`. Hope it makes sense to you. Read more on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-unique) about this.